# How to pass a constructor argument to a Page using ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to pass a constructor argument to a ContentPage inside a Shell like so:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Page1" >
    <ShellContent Title="Page1"
                  Route="Page1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page1}"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

I am unable to find a way to accomplish this.

The following code works, but it loads the page on application startup which is too slow.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Page1" >
    <ShellContent Title="Page1"
                  Route="Page1">
        <views:Page1>
            <x:Arguments>
                <x:Int32>
                    0
                </x:Int32>
            </x:Arguments>
        </views:Page1>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

I need a way to pass a constructor argument using the ContentTemplate/DataTemplate method

Comment: Use dependency injection.

Comment: Where is the value of the parameter come from? I suggest you put the parameter directly inside your `ContentPage`.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I am reusing a ContentPage multiple times and using an int/enum to determine which variation of the ContentPage it currently is.

Comment: My only solution so far is to create subclasses for each variation of the ContentPage but I would like to just use the constructor if I am able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to pass in all data through a DataTemplate like this:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Page1" >
    <ShellContent Title="Page1"
                  Route="Page1">
        <ShellContent.ContentTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>
                <views:Page1>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Int32>
                            0
                        </x:Int32>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </views:Page1>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  `BindableProperty` to achieve this.

You can create a bindable property in the contentpage.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{
      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // Get the value here
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-----------> arg is : " + Arg);
    }
    //add property Arg
    public string Arg
    {
        set { SetValue(ArgProperty, value); }
        get { return (string)GetValue(ArgProperty); }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty ArgProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Arg), typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), string.Empty);

}
```

Usage example:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Page1" > 
    <ShellContent Title="Page1"
              Route="Page1">
        <local:MainPage Arg="test">

        </local:MainPage>
    </ShellContent>
</FlyoutItem>
```